# apt-get upgrade fails, unmet dependencies

Tags: linux, ubuntu

So I seemed to have messed up my system. My last resort is to reinstall Ubuntu, but I'm hoping I can get some suggestions on how to avoid that.

I'm unable to install applications via apt, upgrade fails, and all steps that I've attempted have pulled up other issues.

So its starts off when I attempt to run sudo apt-get upgrade I get this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu11) but 2.23-0ubuntu10 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu11) but 2.23-0ubuntu10 is installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu11) but 2.23-0ubuntu10 is installed
 libc6-x32 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu11) but 2.23-0ubuntu10 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

so using the suggestions I next attempt apt-get -f install and I get this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6 libc6:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6 libc6:i386
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 425 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,838 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 499265 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.23-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libc6:i386 (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...

LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains the traditional /lib directory,
but not the multiarch directory /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.
It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation;
please remove the /lib/directory from LD_LIBRARY_PATH and
try again.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.23-0ubuntu11_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libc6:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...

LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains the traditional /lib directory,
but not the multiarch directory /lib/i386-linux-gnu.
It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation;
please remove the /lib/directory from LD_LIBRARY_PATH and
try again.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu11_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu11_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've found suggestions regarding unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH. i've re-written the LD_LIBRARY_PATH with suggestions from other links. I've removed libc6* and attempted to reinstall and nothing seems to work.

```
~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib

~$ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu11) but 2.23-0ubuntu10 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu11) but 2.23-0ubuntu10 is installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu11) but 2.23-0ubuntu10 is installed
 libc6-x32 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu11) but 2.23-0ubuntu10 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions, or should I just reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Please post output of `echo "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`

Comment: updated post with results of echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `apt-get update` if it didn't work then try `apt-get check` to see if your dependecies aren't harmed

Comment: yes, update works just fine. I don't get any issues when I use update. As far as chec k goes. I get the same issue. . I've updated the original post with the output of check.